# Does the "backspace" key places the cursor on a new line in UNIX V7?

Tags: unix, simh

I am running UNIX V7 using the SimH emulator. Whenever I press the "backspace" key, instead of the previous character being deleted, what happens is that the cursor is placed on a new line.

Is this how the "backspace" key behaves in UNIX V7, or is it just a SimH thing?

Comment: What is the output from `stty -a`?

Comment: @Mick When I do `stty -a` I get an error: *unknown mode: -a*.

Comment: Sorry. I cut my teeth on AIX. You don't need any arguments.

Comment: @Mick `stty` without arguments gives me: *speed 0 baud
erase = '#'; kill = '@'
even -nl echo -tabs cr2*.

Comment: Try `stty erase <backspace key>`.

Comment: @Mick I got an error: *syntax error: `newline' unexpected*.

Comment: In case you misunderstood Mick's comment type the letters `stty erase`, press the space key, press the key you want to use as the backspace key, and then press enter.

Answer (score 5):

By default, the delete character (ASCII 127, ^?) acts as the interrupt key (usually bound to ^C on more modern Unix-like systems).  Pressing the interrupt key will behave as you describe.  In Unix v7 there's no easy way to change this except to modify the kernel.

If your terminal sends a delete character when you press the backspace key, try modifying your terminal settings so that it sends backspace (ASCII 8, ^H) instead.  Then use the following command to get Unix to recognize backspace as the erase character:

```
stty erase '^H'
```

While you're at it, you might want to also set the line-kill key according to modern usage:

```
stty kill '^U'
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following:

1. Find out what your backspace key is generating, by running `od -b`
   then pressing backspace, then ctrl-D. If ctrl-D doesn't work, press up to 16 arbitrary different characters, then press Enter to see the output, then press ctrl-C.
2. Say `stty erase ^H` if backspace generates byte 010, or `stty erase ^_` if backspace generates byte 0177.